# Mstest.exe can't run load tests

Tags: mstest, load-testing

I'm looking for a way to automate load testing, but for some reason, when I'm trying to run through command line (mstest.exe /testroncatiner:) I receive the following message:

> File extension specified '.loadtest' is not a valid test extension.

If I'm trying to run .dll file then another message appears:

> No tests to execute.

Canyou please tell me what am I doing wrong? I have installed Visual Studio 2017 Enterpise

Answer (score 1):

Make sure that you have the web performance and load test component installed. You can find it in the Individual components section of the Visual Studio installer.